# How to allow a particular user to take quiz very next day in drupal

Tags: 7, quiz

I have gone through so many question asked here but not find exact answer. The main problem I have faced is to create a [quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) using 7.x-4.0-rc2, I made some user who can take quiz. One user can take quiz only once, but I need that particular user can take quiz again very next day (After 12AM).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make use of rules:

1. Create user role (by hand) which always access to quiz let say QUIZER
2. On Event "I want to enter Quiz"
3. Look up Time Last entered date from current olr
4. Check if allowed to go on
5. Add role quizer to current user
6. On event "I'm stopping the Quiz"
7. Remove role quizer from current user
8. Save Time last entered Quiz in user profile

Comment: Thanks @Justme for your reply. I tried with rules already what this is also not working as I needed.

Comment: What is not working in rules for this?

Comment: can you please tell me in brief. I am not able to follow the procedure you explain above.... and the main thing am looking for is, If an authentic user failed the quiz today. But i have to make it the way in which User should able to take test again very next day after 12 AM. (Currently in working project user able to take the quiz only after 24 hours.)

Comment: Pls post the following. The steps you need to have in functionality and a export of your current rule