# Code to take quiz again on the next day after user is failed

Tags: 7, quiz

In drupal 6, I had a requirement to enable the users to take the quiz on the next day if they failed and from somewhere I got the following code to make that work. They added one more variables, `time_end` and used `strtotime('today')`

But now I upgraded to Drupal 7 and code for the same a little bit changed and I couldn't make that work. I am looking forward to getting help to achieve it. I am using quiz [quiz-7.x-4.0-rc1](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz)

***Drupal 6 Original lines***

```
// Check to see if this user is allowed to take the quiz again:
  if ($quiz->takes > 0) {
//   $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS takes FROM {quiz_node_results} WHERE uid = %d AND nid = %d";
//   $taken = db_result(db_query($query, $user->uid, $quiz->nid));
```

***Drupal 6 Changed lines*** (only first two lines. after that code remains the same except drupal_set_message.)

```
     $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS takes FROM {quiz_node_results} WHERE uid = %d AND nid = %d AND time_end > %d";
        $taken = db_result(db_query($query, $user->uid, $quiz->nid, strtotime('today')));

    $allowed_times = format_plural($quiz->takes, '1 time', '@count times');
    $taken_times   = format_plural($taken, '1 time', '@count times');
```

***Drupal 7 Original lines.***

```
  // Check to see if this user is allowed to take the quiz again:
  if ($quiz->takes > 0) {
    $taken = db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS takes FROM {quiz_node_results} WHERE uid = :uid AND nid = :nid", array(':uid' => $user->uid, ':nid' => $quiz->nid))->fetchField();
    $allowed_times = format_plural($quiz->takes, '1 time', '@count times');
    $taken_times   = format_plural($taken, '1 time', '@count times');
```

Full drupal 7 code is available here [DrupalContrib](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!quiz!quiz.module/function/quiz_start_check/7)

Comment: Cant you make use of rules instead ?? Have you tried installing rules ??

Comment: quiz-7.x-4.0-rc1 is not integrated with rules...but quiz 5 does. But I am getting so much of problems while upgrading. Anyway thanks for advise.

Comment: Please refer http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/212091/how-to-allow-a-particular-user-to-take-quiz-very-next-day-in-drupal may be this could be of any help

Comment: show o/p of `print_r($quiz);` just above `if ($quiz->takes > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

I could find a solution. It's actually pretty simple. But I don't know whether this is the right way doing it.
Just change `$taken` like below. Then anybody can retake the test on the next day. Thanks to all for the support.

```
$taken = db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS takes FROM {quiz_node_results} WHERE uid = :uid AND nid = :nid AND time_end > :time_end", array(':uid' => $user->uid, ':nid' => $quiz->nid, ':time_end' => strtotime('today')))->fetchField();
```